# how to retrieve values of dynamically generated <tr> in html javascript

Tags: javascript, database, listbox

I have a table generated dynamically having 2 columns using javascript. First column is the list of the items selected from list box and second column is the blank textboxes to enter the quantity. **Now i want to retrieve the values of the first column of the tables to insert into database.** Pls help me how it can be done. So far i have done something like this. I have tried using a hidden text box or a lable having hidden text box. But not able to get the result. (chem_sel2 is name of my listbox)

```
function fun1(){

var my_chem_qty_div = document.getElementById("chem_qty");
var table = document.createElement('TABLE');
table.id='sel_chem_table';
table.border='1';
table.align='center';
table.style.width='100%';
var tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY');
table.appendChild(tableBody);

var chem_sel2_combo =document.getElementById("chem_sel2");

for(var k=0;k<chem_sel2_combo.options.length;k++)
        {
         var tr = document.createElement('TR');
         tableBody.appendChild(tr);

        /*  var td = document.createElement('TD');
        td.width='30';
        td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(chem_sel2_combo.options[k].value));
        tr.appendChild(td);*/

        var td1 = document.createElement('TD');
        var lbl= document.createElement('label');
        var txt=document.createElement('input');
        txt.setAttribute('id','selctd_chem');
        txt.setAttribute('value',chem_sel2_combo.options[k].value);
       // txt.setAttribute('type','hidden');
        lbl.setAttribute('id', 'lbl_txt');
        lbl.setAttribute('value', chem_sel2_combo.options[k].value);
        td1.width='40';

        td1.appendChild(txt);
        td1.appendChild(lbl);
        //td1.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
        tr.appendChild(td1);

        var td2 = document.createElement('TD');
        var txt= document.createElement('input');
        txt.setAttribute('id',"qty_text");
        txt.setAttribute('type','text');
        td2.width='30';
        td2.appendChild(txt);
        tr.appendChild(td2);
}
}
```

Comment: `tr` is never defined.

Comment: @Joe oops Sorry.. I have updated my code with tr..

Comment: @simplecoder...pls help..

Answer (score 1):

Move `tableBody.appendChild(tr);` to the end of the loop. You're appending `tr` to the table before you add anything to the tr.

```
for (...) {
    var tr = ...;
    tr.append(...);
    tableBody.append(tr);
}
```

instead of:

```
for (...) {
    var tr = ...;
    tableBody.append(tr);
    tr.append(...);
}
```